Insertions of the action inside correlators
Suppose I have a scalar field theory described by an action $S[\phi]$ that can be massive $\lambda\phi^4$ theory, what is the effect of inserting a power of the action inside of correlators?
Like:
$$\langle \phi(x_1)\ldots \phi(x_n) S[\phi]^m\rangle$$
What kind of divergences can I expect?
I mean, if the insertions are of the renormalized action. Should I expect the correlator to be finite? I think so, but I am not sure.

The action is a functional of $\phi$ as a function of time, so how exactly are you defining this?

The insertiomn of composite operators at zero momentum, like $\int d^4x \phi^4(x)$

I'm a bit confused about what is the question. The action is an integral over spacetime of a polynomial in the fields and their derivatives. So if you insert the action (or a power thereof) into a correlator you will get integrals of correlators with additional powers of the field. These individual correlators are by themselves computed in perturbation theory by Feynman diagrams and exhibit the usual kind of divergences. So you get an integral with a divergent integrand, the details depending on the specific theory (unless of course you have renormalized and made the correlators finite first).

What I mean is, if the theory has been renormalized, are the insertion finite or does the avtion behaves as a composite operator thst needs separate renormalization?

The answer was very simple. By the fundamental hypothesis of renormalization, the bare and renormalized action are connected by a change of variables with no overall renormalization factor, i.e.
$$ S_B(g_B,m_B,\phi_B)= S(g,m,\phi)$$
where the subscript $B$ stands for bare. A violation of this fact would imply a violation of the Callan-Symanzik equations.
This in turn implies that the action is renormalization-group invariant:
$$\frac{d}{d\log\mu} S=0$$
Where $\mu$ is some subtraction scale. This implies that the insertions of the renormalized action are finite with no extra renormalization needed.

I'll do this in Euclidean space.  The partition function is
$$
Z[\alpha] = \int e^{-\alpha S}
$$
Here $\alpha$ is some overall factor; could be $1/\hbar$, or inverse temperature $\beta$ depending on the context.
A correlation function is
$$
\langle O \rangle_\alpha = \frac{1}{Z[\alpha]}\int O \, e^{-\alpha S}.
$$
We will assume that $O$ does not depend on $\alpha$.  Take derivative w.r.t. $\alpha$ to get:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha} \langle O \rangle_\alpha
=
-\langle O S\rangle_\alpha + \langle O \rangle_\alpha \langle S \rangle_\alpha
$$
Recall that the free energy is $F = -\log Z$, we can rewrite $\langle S \rangle_\alpha = \frac{d}{d\alpha} F$.
Here is the result, but I have no bloody idea how/why this is useful.

Yes this is ok but what about the divergence structure?

@Fra Huh?  Divergence?  Assuming it's the usual $\phi^4$ theory, you just deal with the usual divergences perturbatively.

I mean, insertions of the action do not generate more divergences than the ones found in perturbation theory, right?
